# What's the story of goddess Khīr Bhavānī / Kheer Bhawani (खीर भवानी) of Kashmir?

Tags: devi, goddess, shaktism, kashmir

Khīr Bhavānī (खीर भवानी, क्षीर भवानी या राज्ञा देवी ), literally means - ‘‘Goddess who
eats khīr,’’ or rice pudding, is a very popular deity in the Kashmir regions of India, whose temple stands on an island outside Shrinagar.

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kheer_Bhawani) -

> Kheer Bhawani, Ksheer Bhawani, Tula Mula shrine or mandir or the Ragnya Devi temple is a Hindu
> temple situated at a distance of 25 kilometers (16 mi) north-east of
> Srinagar, Jammu and Kashmir, India, in the village of Tulmul in
> Ganderbal. It is dedicated to the Hindu goddess Kheer Bhavani
> constructed over a sacred spring. As is the custom with Hindu deities,
> the goddess has many names including Ragyna or Rajna, along with
> variations in honorifics such as Devi, Mata, or Bhagavata. The term
> kheer refers to a milk and rice pudding that is offered to propitiate
> the goddess. Kheer Bhawani is sometimes translated as 'Milk Goddess'.
> The worship of Kheer Bhawani is universal among the Hindus of Kashmir,
> most of them who worship her as their protective patron deity
> Kuladevi.

There's also a sacred spring in the temple premises with several legends associated -

[image]

> The legend of the [Sacred Spring](https://www.thedivineindia.com/kheer-bhawani-mandir/6636)
>
> This temple is built on a sacred spring. It is believed that when the water of this spring turns black, it is considered an inauspicious sign for the people living there. It is said that when the floods occurred in Kashmir in 2014, the water of this spring became black.

**Question - Which scriptures mention the deity of Khīr Bhavānī, and the temple, and its associated legends with the sacred Spring?**

Is the story found in canonical scriptures, or is it sthala (local) scriptures only?